# How to select related row from the grid when search using Id

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have one grid which is binded some collections. I need to highlight/select the particular row when search using customer Id in winform application.

Could you please provide any solution for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the name of your DataGridView to be dgv.

To mark it as selected:

```
 dgv.Rows[user_id].Selected = true;
```

To highlight with some color:

```
dgv.Rows[user_id].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SkyBlue; // or any color
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gnqz. I have one more concern. If I have 50 records in the grid. I kept the scroll bar to view the records. If i search 40th record means, in the above code it has been selected. But I couldn't see without I use scroll bar to see that selected item. How Can i focus that item which i searched? I have used GridGroupingControl.

Comment: Look at the dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex property.

Comment: I don't have much reputation to mark up vote. I already tried. Sorry Gnqz.